# Azure APIM VNet Stuck

Tags: azure, apim

I've created an instance of APIM. After placing it in a Virtual Network, when I click on API's It just sits there spinning. If I click add, and attempt to add a new API I get the following error message no matter what "Name" I give it. "One or more fields contain incorrect values:
Name is already in use"

There are no API's so this should not occur at all, for the sake if testing I tried several random strings and it's always the same response.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the ***important*** section in the enable vnet connection article.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-vnet#-enable-vnet-connection

[image: Note and Important section]